# Is there a way to delete DLQ messages under topic subscription azure servicebus through powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, dlq

Am planning to develop an powershell script to delete DLQ messages under Azure servicebus topic subscription, however i could not find any powershell cmdlet to delete the DLQ messages and when i referred some documents it says its not possible to delete the DLQ messages via powershell as it doesnt have any right cmdlet to delete it , so i tried lets try with Restapi method but i couldnt find accurate restapi.
So I have these question

1. Can i use powershell script to delete dlq messages? or
2. Which Restapi can i use for it .

Any suggestion on this is much apprciated. Am eager to write  powershell scriot but want to know is it possible ? Please note : Am not expert in ps script but i write some basic scripts

Thanks in Advace

Comment: You'll need to **receive** and delete those, not delete. Both PowerShell and REST are good options.

Comment: @SeanFeldman sorry didnt get your point. Could you please brief a bit.

Comment: Messages can be received in two modes. One is a [destructive read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/receive-and-delete-message-destructive-read), where a message is read and immediately removed from the broker. If you ignore the contents of the read message, that's, in essence, a purge. That can be done with PowerShell. REST API offers a [delete option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/delete-message).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use PowerShell script to delete dlq messages?

There is no possibility of using PowerShell script to delete dql messages.

Refer [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1099830/azure-service-bus-delete-dlq-message-through-porta) for detailed information on the above approach.

> Which Restapi can I use for it?

You can use the Rest API with URL `https://<serviceNamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<queuePath>/messages/head` for [Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/receive-and-delete-message-destructive-read#request) request as given in the MS Doc.

Or

You can also use `service bus explorer` under Azure service bus from the Portal as shown.

[image]

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818237/19785512) by @Thili for another approach which is using service bus explorer tool to deleted dlq messages.